# Sync a Maildir backup to an account

Tags: email, postfix, backup, dovecot

I have a client who created about 20 mailboxes on a server, and they have been using them for a few weeks. So there is mail in them, that can't be lost.

Now they recovered a backup of those mailboxes from an old hosting company, and they want me to merge those backups with the current mailboxes. I tried a lot of things with dsync and doveadm sync but I can't find the correct syntax, could someone help me ?

Basically, I just want to merge let's say /home/backup/account1/Maildir to /home/vmail/domain.tld/account1/. On this server account1@domain.tld will already be referencing /home/vmail/domain.tld/account1 according to the dovecot configuration, so I should be able to use -u if I understand it correctly, but how do I reference the backup ? looks like doveadm sync is only compatible with an other dovecot server, which I don't have ?
I was thinking about just setting up a whole other mail server and using imapsync, which is really easy to use, but I think there must be a way to do it with doveadm sync or dsync that doesn't involve that must lost time.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use imapcopy or imapsync software to merge servers together. I use it all the time to make mail backups. The downside is you need to know the passwords to the accounts.

https://imapsync.lamiral.info/

Comment: This post is from 2016, but thanks. I do believe I ended up using some perl script, which might be imapsync I'm not sure, to copy the mails, worked great

Comment: Sorry, it was on the "top questions" page and I missed that. I suppose it's because it's not a solved question.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated some time ago mails from an hosting plan to my mail server merging mailboxes.
As you I had a backup of maildirs that contains, in facts, a directory/files structure of your IMAP mailbox.
If you do a `ls -la` into `/home/backup/account1/Maildir` you should see something like:

```
# ls -la
drwx------. 19 vmail vmail  4096  4 mag 18.15 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 vmail vmail  4096 29 nov 17.23 ..
drwx------.  2 vmail vmail  4096  4 mag 18.15 cur
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail   496  4 mag 18.15 dovecot.index
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail 28656  4 mag 18.09 dovecot.index.cache
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail    40  4 mag 18.15 dovecot.index.log
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail 32864  4 mag 18.15 dovecot.index.log.2
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail    23 15 feb 11.22 dovecot-keywords
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail   360 29 nov 17.39 dovecot.mailbox.log
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail   485  4 mag 18.09 dovecot-uidlist
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail     8 29 nov 17.49 dovecot-uidvalidity
-r--r--r--.  1 vmail vmail     0 29 nov 17.37 dovecot-uidvalidity.565b29d3
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail  4096 15 feb 16.24 .Drafts
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail  4096 30 nov 10.38 .Job
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail  4096  3 mag 22.48 .Junk
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail  3056  4 mag 18.09 maildirsize
drwx------.  2 vmail vmail  4096  4 mag 18.15 new
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail  4096 29 nov 17.39 .Newsletter
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail  4096 30 nov 10.38 .Personali
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail  4096 15 feb 16.24 .Sent
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail   140 29 nov 17.39 subscriptions
drwx------.  2 vmail vmail  4096  4 mag 18.09 tmp
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail  4096 29 mar 22.44 .Trash
```

every `.Something` directory is an IMAP folder that contains:

```
# ls -la .Trash/
drwx------.  5 vmail vmail 4096 29 mar 22.44 .
drwx------. 19 vmail vmail 4096  4 mag 18.15 ..
drwx------.  2 vmail vmail 4096 29 mar 22.43 cur
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail 7060 29 mar 22.44 dovecot.index.cache
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail 3136 29 mar 22.44 dovecot.index.log
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail   10  2 gen 20.46 dovecot-keywords
-rw-------.  1 vmail vmail  957 29 mar 22.43 dovecot-uidlist
drwx------.  2 vmail vmail 4096 15 lug  2015 new
drwx------.  2 vmail vmail 4096 29 mar 22.43 tmp
```

`cur` and `new` folders contains your mails for this IMAP folder (each file is a mail), `tmp` is a temp dir and should be empty:

```
# ls -ls .Trash/cur/
 4 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  2039 22 ott  2015 1445534803.M462117P23470V0000000000000901I000000000122C00E_0.srv-nya,S=2039:2,S
 4 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  1191  2 gen 20.45 1451763951.M751917P11002.srv-nya,S=1191,W=1223:2,Sa
64 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail 64457  4 feb 14.57 1454594258.M272724P14796.srv-nya,S=64457,W=65380:2,S
 8 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  5163  7 feb 13.41 1454848911.M448032P9360.srv-nya,S=5163,W=5256:2,S
 4 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  2156 24 feb 10.18 1456305519.M460217P17448.srv-nya,S=2156,W=2200:2,S
 4 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  2193 24 feb 12.07 1456312052.M200955P5273.srv-nya,S=2193,W=2237:2,Sa
 4 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  2200 24 feb 12.12 1456312374.M662245P6161.srv-nya,S=2200,W=2243:2,Sa
 4 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  1518 21 mar 21.36 1458592592.M566137P20473.srv-nya,S=1518,W=1557:2,Sa
12 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  9784 29 mar 12.29 1459247350.M595698P12652.srv-nya,S=9784,W=9937:2,Sa
 8 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  5176 29 mar 13.10 1459249819.M474900P19505.srv-nya,S=5176,W=5269:2,Sa
 8 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  5325 29 mar 14.43 1459255390.M406958P2566.srv-nya,S=5325,W=5427:2,Sa
 8 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  5668 29 mar 19.08 1459271296.M76075P16861.srv-nya,S=5668,W=5765:2,Sa
 8 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  5673 29 mar 19.16 1459271792.M922218P18404.srv-nya,S=5673,W=5770:2,Sa
 8 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  5755 29 mar 20.12 1459275164.M71573P28250.srv-nya,S=5755,W=5853:2,Sa
 8 -rw-------. 1 vmail vmail  5622 29 mar 21.26 1459279615.M929486P8464.srv-nya,S=5622,W=5718:2,Sa
```

You also can see some `dovecot.something` files that are support files for dovecot and the `maildirsize` file that contains info about your IMAP quota (if enabled).

If your old hosting use something different from dovecot (like courier) you will see similar files with names like `courier.*`.

If you want to merge old and new mailboxes you can move all mails files (like `1459279615.M929486P8464.srv-nya,S=5622,W=5718:2,Sa`) to corresponding directory in the new mailbox.

In order to do it you can:

- **TAKE A BACKUP COPY OF OLD AND NEW MAILBOX BEFORE START**
- Recursively remove all `dovecot.*` files and `maildirsize` from
  backup
- Move/copy all other file to the new mailbox merging the directories
  (you should be able to do it with `cd /home/backup/account1/Maildir
  && rsync -av --progress . /home/vmail/domain.tld/account1/`). Note: file names of mails contains mailserver hostname usually, so you should not have filename conflicts.
- Recursively fix permission/file ownership/SELinux context of new mailbox if needed
- Remove the `maildirsize` file from the new mailbox in order to fix the quota count (dovecot will re-create it when a new mail is delivered to this mailbox fixing things)
- From your mail client subscribe all IMAP folders (if needed and not done automatically)

This worked for me, if you want to try I recommend you to test it on a copy of a mailbox first (like create a new mailbox called test@yourdomain.com, copy in it all files of account1@yourdomain.com mailbox, fix permission/file ownership, check that it work trough webmail/IMAP client, merge mailboxes like said before, send a mail to test@yourdomain.com to force maildirsize creation and check again trough IMAP client that all mail all readable)